# SwiftUI can't tap in Spacer of HStack

Tags: ios, swift, swiftui

I've got a List view and each row of the list contains an HStack with some text view('s) and an image, like so:

```
HStack{
    Text(group.name)
    Spacer()
    if (groupModel.required) { Text("Required").color(Color.gray) }
    Image("ic_collapse").renderingMode(.template).rotationEffect(Angle(degrees: 90)).foregroundColor(Color.gray)
}.tapAction { self.groupSelected(self.group) }
```

This seems to work great, except when I tap in the empty section between my text and the image (where the `Spacer()` is) the tap action is not registered. The tap action will only occur when I tap on the text or on the image.

Has anyone else faced this issue / knows a workaround?

Comment: Honest question: Exactly **why** would you expect someone to tap in a `spacer`? It's by definition, space. Maybe your UI is expecting something you might in `UIKit`? If so, please, details it.

Comment: @dfd Each row is simply just text with a chevron at the end of it, something like `Object One                > `, is what the row would look like - and I would want the user to be able to tap anywhere on the row (That did not format with the spaces I thought it would - just imagine a space between the text and the `>`)

Comment: @dfd I think it is pretty standard behaviour to want the user to be able to click anywhere on a table cell, hence why they have a `didSelectRowAt` method on their UIKit table views

Comment: Sure, I agree. But maybe try something else instead of a `Spacer`. Maybe turn the entire thing into a `Button`? In SwiftUI a Spacer is just that - spacing.

Comment: Can't believe I'm going to say this... but yeah, an oldie but goodie! When I suggested a Button I had this in mind: https://alejandromp.com/blog/2019/06/09/playing-with-swiftui-buttons/

Answer (score 299, accepted):

As I've recently learned there is also:

```swift
HStack {
  ...
}
.contentShape(Rectangle())
.onTapGesture { ... }
```

Works well for me.

Comment: This worked perfectly when applied to the contents of my `Button`. No need for the `onTapGesture` in that case.

Comment: Works with an HStack with spacers within it.

Comment: This works well. The accepted answer didn't work for me because it changes the accent color of the contents of the HStack.

Comment: This is also the better solution for my case than the accepted answer as what I have is a line with different controls and not actually a button. But the whole thing should be tappable. Also, as Cloud9999Strife already mentioned it doesn't change the look.

Comment: Some more explanation from Hacking With Swift: https://www.hackingwithswift.com/quick-start/swiftui/how-to-control-the-tappable-area-of-a-view-using-contentshape .

Comment: The fact that this solution is required disappoints me with SwiftUI in general.Anyway great solution!

Comment: Learned the hard way [order matters on modifiers](https://www.hackingwithswift.com/books/ios-swiftui/why-modifier-order-matters), make sure `contentShape` is before `onTapGesture`.

Answer (score 25):

It is better to use a `Button` for accessibility.

```
Button(action: { self.groupSelected(self.group) }) {
    HStack {
        Text(group.name)
        Spacer()
        if (groupModel.required) { Text("Required").color(Color.gray) }
        Image("ic_collapse").renderingMode(.template).rotationEffect(Angle(degrees: 90)).foregroundColor(Color.gray)
    }
}.foregroundColor(.primary)
```

If you don't want the button to apply the accent color to the `Text(group.name)`, you have to set the `foregroundColor` as I did in my example.

Comment: This changes the background color on tap, although you can probably change that: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56509640/how-to-set-custom-highlighted-state-of-swiftui-button

The ZStack solution from @jim-marquardt worked well for me.

Comment: Is not the same behavior with `navigationLink`

Answer (score 21):

works like magic on every view:

```
extension View {
    func onTapGestureForced(count: Int = 1, perform action: @escaping () -> Void) -> some View {
        self
            .contentShape(Rectangle())
            .onTapGesture(count:count, perform:action)
    }
}
```

Comment: This is awesome

Answer (score 20):

The best approach in my opinion for accessibility reasons is to wrap the `HStack` inside of a `Button` label, and in order to solve the issue with `Spacer` can't be tap, you can add a `.contentShape(Rectangle())` to the `HStack`.

So based on your code will be:

```
Button {
    self.groupSelected(self.group)
} label: {
    HStack {
        Text(group.name)
        Spacer()
        if (groupModel.required) {
            Text("Required").color(Color.gray)
        }
        Image("ic_collapse")
            .renderingMode(.template)
            .rotationEffect(Angle(degrees: 90))
            .foregroundColor(Color.gray)
    }
    .contentShape(Rectangle())
}
```

Answer (score 10):

I've been able to work around this by wrapping the Spacer in a ZStack and adding a solid color with a very low opacity:

```
ZStack {
    Color.black.opacity(0.001)
    Spacer()
}
```

Answer (score 10):

Simple extension based on Jim's answer

```
extension Spacer {
    /// https://stackoverflow.com/a/57416760/3393964
    public func onTapGesture(count: Int = 1, perform action: @escaping () -> Void) -> some View {
        ZStack {
            Color.black.opacity(0.001).onTapGesture(count: count, perform: action)
            self
        }
    }
}
```

Now this works

```
Spacer().onTapGesture {
    // do something
}
```

Comment: Can you describe in more detail what this is doing? Is this creating a new ZStack everytime a user taps? Does it clean up the memory from this? This worked great by the way :).

Comment: @JosephAstrahan no it just creates an opaque view behind your current view that registers user taps

Comment: Does it destroy (free the memory) of the view after the tap has finished?

Comment: So it creates a 1 time view? Not creating that view everytime the user taps over and over I guess was my main question.  The reason I asked was because it's within the on TapGesture function which implies it's creating the view over and over again.

Comment: This is a clean answer, especially for tracking phantom taps.

Comment: @JosephAstrahan
@CasperZandbergen
@DaWiseguy Why `self` is 
required inside ZStack?

Comment: @pkc456 use the accepted answer, it is better.

Answer (score 4):

I just add the background color(except `clear` color) for `HStack` works.

```
HStack {
        Text("1")
        Spacer()
        Text("1")
}.background(Color.white)
.onTapGesture(count: 1, perform: {

})
```

Answer (score 2):

Although the accepted answer allows the mimicking the button functionality, visually it does not satisfy. Do not substitute a `Button` with a `.onTapGesture` or `UITapGestureRecognizer` unless all you need is an area which accepts finger tap events. Such solutions are considered hacky and are not good programming practices.

To solve your problem you need to implement the `BorderlessButtonStyle` ⚠️

### Example

Create a generic cell, e.g. `SettingsNavigationCell`.

#### SettingsNavigationCell

```swift
struct SettingsNavigationCell: View {
  
  var title: String
  var imageName: String
  let callback: (() -> Void)?

  var body: some View {
    
    Button(action: {
      callback?()
    }, label: {

      HStack {
        Image(systemName: imageName)
          .font(.headline)
          .frame(width: 20)
        
        Text(title)
          .font(.body)
          .padding(.leading, 10)
          .foregroundColor(.black)
        
        Spacer()
        
        Image(systemName: "chevron.right")
          .font(.headline)
          .foregroundColor(.gray)
      }
    })
    .buttonStyle(BorderlessButtonStyle()) // <<< This is what you need ⚠️
  }
}
```

#### SettingsView

```swift
struct SettingsView: View {
  
  var body: some View {
    
    NavigationView {
      List {
        Section(header: "Appearance".text) {
          
          SettingsNavigationCell(title: "Themes", imageName: "sparkles") {
            openThemesSettings()
          }
          
          SettingsNavigationCell(title: "Lorem Ipsum", imageName: "star.fill") {
            // Your function
          }
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Just adding an empty background modifier works.

```
HStack {
  ...
}
.background()
.onTapGesture { ... }
```

Answer (score 1):

I've filed [feedback](https://feedbackassistant.apple.com/) on this, and suggest you do so as well.

In the meantime an opaque `Color` should work just as well as `Spacer`.  You will have to match the background color unfortunately, and this assumes you have nothing to display behind the button.

Answer (score 1):

**Kinda in the spirit of everything that has been said:**

```
struct NoButtonStyle: ButtonStyle {
    func makeBody(configuration: Configuration) -> some View {
        configuration.label
            .background(Color.black.opacity(0.0001))
    }
}
extension View {
    func wrapInButton(action: @escaping () -> Void) -> some View {
        Button(action: action, label: {
            self
        })
        .buttonStyle(NoButtonStyle())
    }
}
```

I created the `NoButtonStyle` because the `BorderlessButtonStyle` was still giving an animation that was different than `.onTapGesture`

**Example:**

```
HStack {
    Text(title)
    Spacer()
    Text("Select Value")
    Image(systemName: "arrowtriangle.down.square.fill")
}
.wrapInButton {
    isShowingSelectionSheet = true
}
```

**Another option:**

```
extension Spacer {
    func tappable() -> some View {
        Color.blue.opacity(0.0001)
    }
}
```

#### Updated:

I've noticed that `Color` doesn't always act the same as a `Spacer` when put in a stack, so I would suggest not using that Spacer extension unless you're aware of those differences. (A spacer pushes in the single direction of the stack (if in a `VStack`, it pushes vertically, if in a `HStack`, it pushes out horizontally, whereas a `Color` view pushes out in all directions.)

Answer (score 0):

This website helped answer the same question for me:
https://www.hackingwithswift.com/quick-start/swiftui/how-to-control-the-tappable-area-of-a-view-using-contentshape

Try applying `.ContentShape(Rectangle())` to the `HStack`.

Answer (score 0):

An update to sergioblancoo's answer.

```
Button {
  self.groupSelected(self.group)
}, label: {
  HStack {
    Text(group.name)
    Spacer()
    if (groupModel.required) {
      Text("Required").color(Color.gray)
    }
    Image("ic_collapse")
      .renderingMode(.template)
      .rotationEffect(Angle(degrees: 90))
      .foregroundColor(Color.gray)
  }
}
```

Just wrap your entire view in a button without the `contentShape`