# SwiftUI: Change List row Highlight colour when tapped

Tags: swiftui, swiftui-list

The default colour of a list row when tapped is grey.

I know how to change background colour using  .listRowBackground, but then it changes to the whole list.

How can I change to a custom colour when tapped, so ONLY the tapped row stays red?

```
import SwiftUI

struct ExampleView: View {
    @State private var fruits = ["Apple", "Banana", "Grapes", "Peach"]

    var body: some View {
        NavigationView {
            List {
                ForEach(fruits, id: \.self) { fruit in
                    Text(fruit)
                }
                .listRowBackground(Color.red)

            }


        }
    }


}

struct ExampleView_Previews: PreviewProvider {
    static var previews: some View {
        ExampleView()
    }
}
```

[image]

Comment: Consider approaches provided in [SwiftUI List with NavigationLink how to make custom highlight on tap](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59089400/swiftui-list-with-navigationlink-how-to-make-custom-highlight-on-tap)

Comment: Does this answer your question? [SwiftUI List with NavigationLink how to make custom highlight on tap](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59089400/swiftui-list-with-navigationlink-how-to-make-custom-highlight-on-tap)

Answer (score 34, accepted):

First, you want the `.listRowBackground` modifier on each row, not the whole list. You can then use it to conditionally set the background color on each row.

If you save the tapped row's ID in a `@State` var, you can set the row to red or the default color based on selection state.  Here's the code:

```
import SwiftUI

struct ContentView: View {
    @State private var fruits = ["Apple", "Banana", "Grapes", "Peach"]
    @State private var selectedFruit: String?

    var body: some View {
        NavigationView {
            List(selection: $selectedFruit) {
                ForEach(fruits, id: \.self) { fruit in
                    Text(fruit)
                        .tag(fruit)
                        .listRowBackground(fruit == selectedFruit ? Color.red : nil)
                }
            }
        }
    }
}

struct ContentView_Previews: PreviewProvider {
    static var previews: some View {
        ContentView()
    }
}
```

Comment: Can this be made to work with non-ForEach-based lists? Such as ones using the built-in selection-management feature? `List(values, selection: $selection) { val in`?

Comment: I would think it should work and is likely to be a better overall solution.  This particular solution is only trying to directly answer the original question, not to suggest a best practice.  Give it a shot and if you have trouble getting what you want, ask a new question and post a comment with a link to it.

Comment: How to make it for a `LazyVStack` ?

Comment: doesn't work when the cell is in a navigationLink

Comment: it doesn't work if the cell is in a navigationLink...

Comment: I was able to get it to work with a NavigationLink embedded in a NavigationStack after all.

Answer (score 10):

Following on @Chuck H,

I'm using:

```
        List {
            ForEach(viewModel.sharingGroups, id: \.self) { group in
                Button(action: {
                    self.selectedGroup = group
                }, label: {
                    Text(group.name)
                })
                .listRowBackground(self.selectedGroup == group ? Color.gray : Color(UIColor.systemGroupedBackground))
            }
        }
```

If you use a Button instead if Text directly, this enables me to tap anywhere on the row, not just on the text.

Comment: better user experience with this one

Answer (score 3):

Here is improved elegant solution without buttons, whole row is tappable. Works on iOS13 too.

```
@ObservedObject var viewModel: TypesListViewModel
@State private var selectedType: Type?   

 List{
       ForEach(viewModel.types, id: \.id){ type in
            TypeRowView(type: type)
                 .contentShape(Rectangle()) //makes whole row tappable
                 .onTapGesture {
                      selectedType = type
                     }
                 .listRowBackground(selectedType == type ? Color(.systemFill) : Color(.systemBackground))
           }//ForEach
       }//List
```

Comment: The only thing missing is removing highlighting after the tap ends.

Answer (score 1):

If you are seeking an alternative for styling purposes on iOS and don't want to introduce state management, since Lists are backed by a UITableView you can use

```
UITableViewCell.appearance().selectedBackgroundView = UIView()
```

to remove the selection color entirely. OR:

```
UITableViewCell.appearance().selectedBackgroundView = {
            let view = UIView()
            view.backgroundColor = .blue
            return view
        }()
```

to set a specific highlight color

Be warned that this applies to the whole application, and only on platforms that support the UITableView, so MacOS or WatchOS would need another solution.

Comment: Thank you for this. This is exactly what I was looking for. Great solution.

Comment: This isn't working for me. (at least if I changed the row background color before)

Answer (score 0):

Apple has silly things breaking in SwiftUI. After banging my head against wall, finally i got some success. Just add a Zstack and Empty Button.

```css
var body: some View {
    List {
        ForEach(data, id: \.self) { item in
            ZStack {
                Button("") {}
                NavigationLink(destination: ItemView(item: item)) {
                    ItemRow(item: item)
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: doesn't work in iOS 15

Comment: Just worked for me with iOS 15 without a NavigationLink

Answer (score 0):

Not perfect but it works, please leave a comment if you have an improvement:

```
struct CustomNavigationLink<ContentView: View, DestinationView: View>: View {

    let content: () -> ContentView
    let destinationView: () -> DestinationView
    @State private var showDetail = false
    @State private var isTouchDown = false

    var body: some View {
        ZStack(alignment: .leading) {
            Color(.red)
                .opacity(isTouchDown ? 0.3 : 0)
            HStack {
                content()
                Spacer()
                NavigationLink(destination: destinationView(),
                               isActive: self.$showDetail) { EmptyView() }
                               .hidden()
                               .frame(width: 0)
                Image(systemName: "chevron.right")
                    .foregroundColor(.red)
            }
            .contentShape(Rectangle())
            .onTapGesture {
                showDetail = true
            }
            ._onButtonGesture { isTouchDown in
                withAnimation {
                    self.isTouchDown = isTouchDown
                }
            } perform: {}
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

In SwiftUI, you can change the List row highlight color when tapped by using the .tint() modifier applied to the List. This will modify both the tint color of the List and the selection color. Here's an example:

```
struct ExampleView: View {
    @State private var fruits = ["Apple", "Banana", "Grapes", "Peach"]

    var body: some View {
        NavigationView {
            List {
                ForEach(fruits, id: \.self) { fruit in
                    Text(fruit)
                }
                .tint(Color.red) // Change this color to your desired row highlight color
            }

        }
    }
}
```

You can replace `Color.red` with any other color you'd like to use for the row highlight.

Remember that the `.tint()` modifier is available only in iOS 15 and later.
If you need to support earlier versions of iOS, you might need to consider alternative solutions, such as custom row views and managing the selection state manually.

Comment: This isn't affecting the selection colour.

Comment: @TimWindsorBrown it actually does on iPadOS with a .automatic list style. Could you please provide more context?

Answer (score -1):

I appreciate all answers but non of them worked for me, so I wanted to share my solution.

The heart of the functionality is rely on `.onAppear` of the centre view (in iPad solid view mode) after cell is selected, detail view displays and fire the 2nd action. Here second action that I need was to set the `selectedIndex` for keeping the selected cell in the selected colour.

I put a simplified version of my code.
I hope it helps for specific cases.

```
@State private var selectedIndex: Int?
var body: some View {
    List{
        ForEach( vm.qCategories.indices, id: \.self ){ index in
            NavigationLink{
                SplitCentreView()
                .onAppear{
                    selectedIndex = index
                    print("selectedIndex: \(String(describing: selectedIndex))")
                }
            } label:{
                ItemRowView(index: index)
            }
            // Selected cell colour
            .listRowBackground(selectedIndex == index ? Color(.systemFill) : Color(.secondarySystemGroupedBackground))
            .buttonStyle(PlainButtonStyle())
            
            
        } // foreach
    } // list
}
```