# How can I set a custom background color for a SwiftUI list item while keeping the standard navigation link highlighting animation?

Tags: swiftui, swiftui-navigationlink

In the following piece of code, as soon as I add the "listRowBackground" portion, the list item is colored correctly, but it no longer is highlighted when the user taps onto it:

```
struct ContentView: View {
    var body: some View {

        let paleRed = Color(red: 1.0, green: 0.7, blue: 0.7, opacity: 0.3)

        NavigationView {
            List {
                NavigationLink ("Goto Hello"){
                    Text("Hello, world!")
                }.listRowBackground(paleRed)
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Is there any other way to color the list items that does not interfere with the highlight animation?

Or is the only solution to somehow create a similar animation from scratch using the intended background color and a second highlight color?

Comment: Possible duplicate: https://stackoverflow.com/q/59141688/3151675

Comment: I do not think it is a duplicate, as that question is about applying some kind of static highlight color to a bunch of list items. It is not about the standard animation when tapping a NavLink, which I want to preserve (or in the worst case re-create), despite having a custom overall color scheme.

Answer (score 0):

Also ran into this problem and my conclusion was there's no way to do it with `NavigationLink`.

I ended up using [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/60996185/16270458). I'm using a plain list style so it looked a bit different.

Here's the button style

```
struct PlainListButton: ButtonStyle {
    let color: Color
    let pressedColor: Color
    
    func makeBody(configuration: Configuration) -> some View {
        configuration.label
            .frame(maxWidth: .infinity, maxHeight: .infinity, alignment: .leading)
            .contentShape(Rectangle())
            .background(configuration.isPressed ? pressedColor : color)
    }
}
```

And here's an example of usage

```
ForEach(items, id: \.self) { item in
    Button {
        //I am using a navigation stack, so I append to that to trigger navigation
    } label: {
        HStack{
            VStack(alignment: .leading){
                Text(item.name)
            }
            Spacer()
            Image(systemName: "chevron.forward")
        }
        .padding //Your preference
    }
    .buttonStyle(PlainListButton(color: YourColorHere, pressedColor: YourColorHere))
    //List row separator configuration here if you want it
}
.listRowBackground(Color.clear)
.listRowInsets(...) //Your preference here
```