# List with different colour selection bar

Tags: swiftui, swiftui-list

I am new to SwiftUI, and I have a simple question. I want to create a list that when the user selects a value the highlighted bar is a different colour from the default system "blue".

[image: Here is my list with the blue bar]

This view is built with this code:

```
struct Test: View {
    @State private var selection: String?

       let names = [
           "Cyril",
           "Lana",
           "Mallory",
           "Sterling"
       ]

       var body: some View {
           NavigationStack {
               List(names, id: \.self, selection: $selection) { name in
                   Text(name)
               }
               .navigationTitle("List Selection")
           }
       }
}
```

I can't seem to change the colour of that bar. How can I do that?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For iOS, see [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/59350920/5133585).

For macOS, this color is determined by the user's macOS settings. This one:

[image]

If this is set to "multicolor", the color will be your app's "AccentColor", as in your asset catalog.

As far as I know, there is no way to change this with the built-in `List` with a `selection:` parameter. You would need to roll your own selection mechanism. Here is a very simple example.

```
@State private var selection: String?

let names = [
    "Cyril",
    "Lana",
    "Mallory",
    "Sterling"
]

var body: some View {
    NavigationStack {
        List(names, id: \.self) { name in
            
            Text(name)
                .onTapGesture {
                    selection = name
                }
                .listRowBackground(name == selection ? Color.red : nil)
        }
        .navigationTitle("List Selection")
    }
}
```

Comment: That works (at least on my build machine). It's the AccentColor in the asset catalog that did it for the default selection within the app and your code is the other way of doing it. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

use `listRowBackground` modifier

```swift
...
Text(name)
  .listRowBackground(name == selection ? Color.red : nil)
...
```

Comment: I thought of this too, but this doesn't actually work on macOS, at least not on 14.1.1.

Comment: Thanks but I concur with @Sweeper this doesn't work on MacOS unfortunately.

Comment: My guess is that the list doesn't update because the ids of the list items have not changed. You can force the `List` to be rebuilt by tying its id to the selection, eg `.id(selection ?? "")`, but this is a heavy workaround and will cause the scroll position to be lost.